# Subscribe method returns json object as undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Today I had a very interesting bug in my Ionic 2 project. I have Asp.net REST API. I make a call from provider to rest api to get the machines. The problem is it is mapped as JSON and when I print its JSON  format it shows the Json object array. However, after mapping when I subscribe it, it shows undefined.

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:19496/api/user(1982)/Machines',config).map(res=>console.log(res.json()));
```

it shows as :
[image]

it is ok.But when I subscribe it, it returns the data undefined:

```
subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data)
  })
```

I have not changed the code.Last week it was working, but when I returned from the holiday and it did not work.

Comment: Check that in your .map your are returning the res.json() result and not the console.log() call. Then you can use the error callback on .subscribe to see what is happening `subscribe(data=>{console.log(data)}, err => {console.log(err)})`

Answer (score 4):

Based on what I can see in the question, the problem is that you're not returning anything from the `map`:

```
return this.http.get('...',config)
           .map(res=>console.log(res.json()));
```

That's why `undefined`is being returned when you subscribe to that. Try by returning the response after printing it in the console:

```
return this.http.get('...',config)
           .map(res => res.json())
           .map(res => { 
             console.log(res);
             return res; // <- Here! :)
           });
```

Comment: Did not work still gets the json data undefined when I subscribe

Comment: If you add an error handler, does it print something else in the console?: `subscribe(data=>{console.log(data)}, err => {console.log(err)})`

Comment: I did what you have just said but it did not still work.